# Containers and Virtual Machines

Tags: azure

I have been studying fundamentals of cloud architecture lately and I  am finding it difficult to understand the difference between a container and a virtual machine in Azure.
First I thought a VM has an operating system while containers don't since the are used to serve libraries then I don't know what to believe again. I need an explanation please.

Answer (score 0):

Within each virtual machine runs a unique guest operating system. VMs with different operating systems can run on the same physical server—a UNIX VM can sit alongside a Linux VM, and so on. Each VM has its own binaries, libraries, and applications that it services, and the VM may be many gigabytes in size.

[image]